# Contain draggable element based on offset of one of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable container that holds a varying amount of children displayed side by side with `display: inline-block`. I want the containment to be based on the offset of either the first or last child, so the user is able to drag all but one (either first or last) offscreen in either direction.

```
drag: function(){//prevent dragging once last element offset is within 10% of window width
  if ($('.element:last').offset().left < $(window).width() * .10)){
    return false;
  }
}
```

The problem is that once I return false, I can no longer drag. Some variation of containment seems like the only option here, but I'm not quite sure how to feed it such a complicated condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was putting everything inside an object that gets passed to the `draggable` method. Once I have the object I can update the containment property whenever the position of the child changes. After it's set, I can reinitialize `draggable`.

```
var borg = {
  axis: 'x',
  drag:function(){}
}
$('#draggable').draggable(borg);
//set property after each time the child offset changes
borg.containment = [
  -1 * ($('.child:first').offset().left + $(window).width() * .18), //x1
  0,          
  $(window).width()/2, //x2
  0
];
//reinitialize
$('#draggable').draggable(borg);
//would $('#draggable').draggable('destroy').draggable(borg) be better or unnecessary?
```